# Concate Primary Keys in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, concatenation

I want to concate `Primary Keys` of multiple tables in `SQL` directly. I used below query to concate three primary keys with a hyphen between them but the `SQL` skipped the hyphen and sum up the primary keys and result in a single value.

```
  SELECT CID + '-' + RID + '-'+  CGID As [IdCombination] ...
```

where CID , RID and CGID are the `Primary Keys` of three `SQL` Tables.

How it skipped the `string` part in query ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Updated**

For Example : The Values of CID , RID and CGID are 3 , 4, 3 respectively. It should be 3-4-3 but the result is 10.

Comment: `select (cast cid as nvarchar(20)) + '-' + ...`

Comment: The strange behaviour of `SELECT CAST('-' AS INT)` let me ask a question myself: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38329343/5089204 Might be interesting to follow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening?  Remember that `+` means both addition and string concatenation.  It so happens that `-` can be interpreted as a number (like `-0`), so SQL Server prefers to interpret the `+` as addition.

Normally, when you do this type of operation, the separation character cannot be interpreted as a number, and you just get an error.  I am amused that you don't get an error in this case.

One method is to explicitly cast the values as strings:

```
SELECT CAST(CID as VARCHAR(255)) + '-' + CAST(RID +  as VARCHAR(255)) '-'+  CAST(CGID  as VARCHAR(255)) As [IdCombination]
```

In SQL Server 2012+, you can do this more simply using `CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CID, '-', RID, '-', 'CGID) As [IdCombination]
```

`CONCAT()` knows that everything should be a string.

Comment: Is `CONCAT()` available in SQL 2012 only ? I am using SQL 2008.

Comment: @Abdul yes it's available from 2012+.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 5 + '-' +  8
```

The output is 13. I must admit, that I did not expect this...

And now try this

```
SELECT CAST('-' AS INT)
```

The result is 0. As your select starts with an INT, SQL Server tries to do a summa of int values. As the single hyphen is casteable to int implicitly, this returns the summa of your values...

The solution, as pointed out by others is either a cast of your column values to a string type or the usage of `CONCAT`

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo. It's really helpful. I understand the reason why it  sum up the values.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see output, but I am assuming, some ID is stored as int and it is being counted, so you should use

```
SELECT Cast(CID as Varchar(50)) + '-' + Cast(RID as Varchar(50)) + '-'+  Cast(CGID as Varchar(50)) As [IdCombination]
```